# PrettyPhoto links wont work in Woocommerce short description area. Does it strip out JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add some links in the short description area and call the pretty photo modal window that comes with woocommerce. Since I am on the product page I should not have to make any additions to the functions.php as far as I can tell, and when I put the same exact code on the regular description it works just fine, but when in the short description instead of opening up a modal it takes me to the image file page instead of having it in the modal.

When inspecting the element it appears the JS event is not on the one in the short description, but it is in the regular description. So strange any thoughts. The link is just a normal link with the photo for the href and dat-rel to indicate the prettyPhoto

```
    <a title="My Picture 1" href="link here" data-rel="prettyPhoto">Size Chart</a>
```

Anyone know why this may be happening?

Comment: The short description is the WordPress excerpt, which has always stripped out HTML.

Comment: i see ok thanks for the clarification helgatheviking

Comment: I should add that you'll be better off adding some content to the `woocommerce_single_product_summary` action hook where the short description is being displayed